# Show that AB - BA = I is impossible for n x n matrices of real or complex numbers.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that AB-BA = I is impossible for n x n matrices of real or complex numbers.
Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Take the trace.

Comment: Use that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same trace.